# Open Javascript Function via Css file

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

i have a problem, I want to use a Javascript Function when someone clicks on a Picture at a website. I used Wordpress Avada to build the site and now I want to use build a custom overlay. But I can't add the Javascript Function ("on()") to the image ( no such option). Is there a way to use a css class to add the function to the elements Thanks for any kind of helpful reply ^^

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no such thing in CSS.

But you can assign class you mentioned, eg. `.onclick-class`

Then you can attach your behaviour in javascript file:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".onclick-class") //picks all elements with your class
elements.forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", on)) //attach click listener to call your "on()" function to every element
```

Keep in mind whenever this javascript code is loaded, all the elements must already exist in the DOM.